# View Microsoft Security Essentials Logs

Tags: windows-7, ms-security-essentials

I have Windows 7 with Security Essentials as anti-virus program.

Recently I plugged in a flash drive and SE quarantined some important files.

I tried Restore option, but failed with some error.

Now I need to at least find the names of the affected files. Is there any way I can view it's log files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what i can tell, and from MS's [own knowledge base](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/mse-protect_scanning/how-can-you-check-the-details-of-your-last-virus/25a5032b-4c54-413f-895d-38805682c96a) - MSSE's logs are stored in 
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Support`. Digging a bit, i found that they seem to be stored in a text file called MPLog--.

There's a LOT of logs there, so you may want to do a search for the word quarantine.

Here's an example of a quarantined entry on mine

```
2012-05-11T11:07:38.022Z DETECTIONEVENT Worm:Win32/Autorun!inf file:D:\autorun.inf;
2012-05-11T11:07:38.092Z DETECTION_ADD Worm:Win32/Autorun!inf file:D:\autorun.inf
Begin Resource Scan
Scan ID:{1E60AF65-9582-446B-AF42-52A7F54D90FF}
Scan Source:6
Start Time:‎05‎-‎11‎-‎2012 19:07:42
End Time:‎05‎-‎11‎-‎2012 19:07:42
Explicit resource to scan
Resource Schema:file
Resource Path:D:\autorun.inf
Result Count:1
Threat Name:Worm:Win32/Autorun!inf
ID:2147597307
Severity:5
Number of Resources:1
Resource Schema:file
Resource Path:D:\autorun.inf
Extended Info:209085274001943
End Scan
***********************************************************
```

*

Comment: I can't find the path in Windows 7

Comment: looks like i messed up the path - its microsoft anti malware

Comment: Nobody answered this yet!
Well, I solved the problem by using a recovery software mentioned in the first reply (which is now deleted for some reason)